# What's wrong with this cumulative sum?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get [1,3,6] as the result. Am I missing something really obvious? The error I got is: `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
def cumulative_sum(n):
    cum_sum = []
    y = 0
    for i in n:
        y += n[i]
        cum_sum.append(y)

    print cum_sum

a = [1,2,3]
cumulative_sum(a)
```

Comment: you need to read tutorial.

Comment: And you need to learn `print` debugging.

Comment: There's a distinction between iterating over the items in a container (with for i in some_container:) and iterating over the range of indexes that would be valid for a list (or array or other numerically indexed object) using ''for i in range(len(some_list)):''

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def cumulative_sum(n):
    cum_sum = []
    y = 0
    for i in n:   # <--- i will contain elements (not indices) from n
        y += i    # <--- so you need to add i, not n[i]
        cum_sum.append(y)
    print cum_sum

a = [1,2,3]
cumulative_sum(a)
```

Arrays are zero-based in Python, so when you confused `n[i]` with `i`, you were accessing `n[3]` while `n` only goes from 0 to 2.

Comment: actually, the `print` statement should be `return cum_sum`, right?

Comment: @Kimvais: I suppose, if he does indeed want it returned rather than printed. He said `print`, so I also said `print`.

Comment: yep - but he was asking _What's wrong_ :) - I _assume_ that the function was supposed to just calculate the cumulative sum, not print it.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with your loop:

```
for i in n:
    y += n[i]
```

The `for` loop is iterating over the *values* of `n`, not the indexes. Change `y += n[i]` to `y += i`.

The exception is raised on the third pass through the loop (when i is 3), since 3 is not in the bounds of the array (valid indexes are [0-2]).

If you want to loop over the indexes as well, you can use the built-in `enumerate` function:

```
for i, x in enumerate(n):
    assert n[i] == x
```

Comment: In the loop, he wants to add `i` at each iteration, not `n`. So not `y += n`, but `y += i`.

Comment: @eumiro: Wow, what was I thinking! That's what I meant, but not what I wrote. Good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple generator based implementation:

```
def cumsum(seq):
    s= 0
    for c in seq:
       s+= c
       yield s

print [c for c in cumsum(range(7))]
print [c for c in cumsum((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))]
```

Which is IMHO quite Pythonic way to implement cumsum.

But here is a more pragmatic implementation, which allows you to handle (allmost) all types where addition may make sense.

```
def cumsum(seq):
    s= seq[0]
    for k in xrange(1, len(seq)):
        yield s
        s= s+ seq[k]
    yield s

print [c for c in cumsum(range(7))]
print [c for c in cumsum((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))]
print [c for c in cumsum(['a', 'b', 'c'])]
print [c for c in cumsum([['a'], ['b'], ['c']])]
print [c for c in cumsum((('a', ), ('b', ), ('c', )))]
```

So all of these examples behaves expected way, which is not true with the more `Pythonic` version. Try it out yourself and figure out the reason for different behaviour.

**Update:**
Based on comments, a more generic cumsum would be like:

```
def cumsum(iterable):
    iterable= iter(iterable)
    s= iterable.next()
    yield s
    for c in iterable:
        s= s+ c
        yield s

tests= [
    [],
    [1],
    [1, 2],
    range(7),
    (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    [['a'], ['b'], ['c']],
    (('a', ), ('b', ), ('c', )),
    xrange(7),
    ]

for test in tests:
    print test, '=> ', list(cumsum(test))
```

Still two yields, but IMHO it's still very readable. And the implementation has now the emphasis that the type of the first element of iterable dictates how addition is expected to behave with the rest of elements.

Comment: Plus points for writing a gnerator, but instead of initializing c to seq[0] and then creating a range of indexes starting at 1, just iterate over the sequence:  cum = 0; for c in seq: cum += c; yield cum   No need for two yields, no need for indexed access, uses an iterator, works with sequences where indexed access is not supported.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Please note that what you comment is implemented in my first cumsum. However please try to harness it with all examples related to my second implementation, so you see the difference. Even the first one is kind of pythonic the second one can handle a much larger scope. I fetched this from my old notes back when I was first learning basics of Python. IMHO these two implementations are simple but valuable examples when learning Python. Thanks

Comment: @Paul McGuire: What one needs is a method which combines the better features of both implementations. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a robust enough function that works on any iterable over objects that support `+` and on any Python from 2.3 onwards (just fiddle with the `print` and `xrange` to make the test infrastructure work with 3.x):

```
Python 2.3.5 (#62, Feb  8 2005, 16:23:02) [MSC v.1200 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def cumsum(iterable):
...     first = True
...     for v in iterable:
...         if first:
...             tot = v
...             first = False
...         else:
...             tot = tot + v
...         yield tot
...
>>> def squares(start, stop):
...     for i in xrange(start, stop):
...         yield i * i
...
>>> tests = [
...     [],
...     [1],
...     [1, 2],
...     range(7),
...     (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
...     ['a', 'b', 'c'],
...     [['a'], ['b'], ['c']],
...     (('a', ), ('b', ), ('c', )),
...     squares(1, 5),
...     ]
>>>
>>> for test in tests:
...     print test, list(cumsum(test))
...
[] []
[1] [1]
[1, 2] [1, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
['a', 'b', 'c'] ['a', 'ab', 'abc']
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']] [['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
(('a',), ('b',), ('c',)) [('a',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
<generator object at 0x014B6A58> [1, 5, 14, 30]
>>>
```

Comment: `a robust enough function that works on any iterable`, not quite. Consider input for example ['a', 1]. I have the same 'defect' in my code, but that's not the the point I was trying to make. It's more on the semantics how += operates on mutable and immutable types. Also I don't value unnessecary testing in the loop ;-). Thanks

Comment: @eat: You left out some of what I wrote: "over objects that support +". About "unnessecary testing in the loop": I'm looking forward to seeing your solution for a combination of (1) iterable instead of sequence and (2) arbitrary "addable" types instead of just numbers. By the way, your second piece of code falls over when fed an empty sequence.

Comment: My intention was not to undervalue your code, just to point out what kind of semantic problems may emerge with cumsum. Yes my second cumsum didn't acknowledge empty ones. But I think I now have in my answer update quite a reasonable implementation. Still care to share any further toughts? Thanks

Comment: @eat: Your update is not unreasonable :-) By the way, using `xrange()` as a test case proves nothing; xrange supports subscripting and will work with your 2nd code. Try `o = xrange(4000, 5000); print o[100]; print o[10]; print len(o)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for I in n:
    # I will be an item from n
    y+=I
```

or what you tried to do:

```
for i in range(len(n)):
    # i is an int that you can index with
    y+=n[i]
```