# Sum one column of a list(follow up)

Tags: python

I have a list that that looks like this:

```
('string ', 'time', 'SPY', 0, 0, 131.63, 100),
('sting ', 'time', 'SPY', 0, 0, 131.63, 700)
```

what I want to do is add the last column of data

What I though to do is unzip the list and then sum the absolute value of the date in the last column but I cant get it to work correctly

what I have been trying is this:

```
testsum = sum(abs(zip(*list[:-1]))
```

thanks

EDIT:
Ok so thanks for the response

```
sum(l[-1]) for l in list
```

worked well but I forgot to mention that I have it running in a for loop and what I really want to do is add all the sums that are outputted I'm really confused and am unsure how to do that I though I could do the same thing again but it didnt work

Comment: Your problem was where you were doing the list slice. `sum(zip(*l)[-1])` would work. (Obviously, under 3.x, where `zip()` returns a generator, you would need to encase in `list()`).

Comment: You also can't use `abs` the way you are trying `abs((1, -2))` does not work. `map(abs,(1,-2))` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generator expressions are your friend:

```
sum(l[-1] for l in list)
```

(although I do hope your list isn't literally called 'list', since that would shadow the builtin).

For the followup, it does depend on exactly what you mean by 'add all the sums that are outputted'. This could mean have some number of lists like the one you posted that you're iterating over, and you want to add all the sums together once. This would be:

```
sum(sum(l[-1] for l in list) for list in lists)
```

Or even just

```
sum(l[-1] for l in list for list in lists)
```

If you mean you want a cumulative sum - so, you want the running total at each stage as another inner sum is added to it - take a look at [this previous question about cumulative sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844399/whats-wrong-with-this-cumulative-sum), or just write out the loop:

```
cumsum = 0
for list in lists:
   cumsum += sum(l[1] for l in list)
   print(cumsum)
```

Comment: @lvc follow up question I have this sum running in a for loop and now I want to sum all the previous sums how would I do that?

Comment: @user1440194 it depends what your data and your loop look like. But, in general, you can replace an accumulator loop that does `total = 0; for item in iterable: total += func(item)` with `sum(func(item) for item in iterable)`, even if `func` itself is another call to `sum` with a generator depending on `item`. But in that case, there might be a better way to code it - depending on your data. If you mean you want a cumulative sum, see, eg, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844399/whats-wrong-with-this-cumulative-sum

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
li = [('string ', 'time', 'SPY', 0, 0, 131.63, 100),
      ('sting ', 'time', 'SPY', 0, 0, 131.63, 700)]
```

this will work:

```
sum(i[-1] for i in li)
800
```

**Update**: in response to updated/edited question:

It is not clear how your list `li` would get its values inside the loop, but in general if you had some construct like

```
some_limit = .. # how often you need to loop
total = 0
for i in range(some_limit):
   # get new/updated values for li
   total += sum(i[-1] for i in li)  

print 'Your total is: ', total
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum([item[-1] for item in list])` you can use list comprehensions.